# Best practice or shortcut for setting the tzinfo to the datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Is there a shortcut for the pieces of code described below:

```
if value.tzinfo is None:
    value = default_tzinfo.localize(value)
    new_value = value.astimezone(default_tzinfo)
else:
    new_value = value
```

I tried to use `datetime.replace()` but returns GMT -8 instead of -7 when I use US/Pacific time zone.

See: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/pacific-time/pacific-daylight-time.htm

```
value = value.replace(tzinfo=default_tzinfo)
```

Example output:

```
2012-05-06 13:12:45-08:00
US/Pacific
---
2012-05-07 00:12:45+03:00
Europe/Istanbul
```

Comment: Where is `default_tzinfo` coming from? I don't think it's part of the standard Python packages.

Comment: Yes, I use pytz. `from pytz import timezone; default_tzinfo = timezone('US/Pacific')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given in the pytz documentation: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic

Once you've used `localize` you should have a datetime with the proper timezone. The call to `astimezone` is redundant and may be messing you up.

The time zone needs to know the date and time so that it can adjust itself for daylight savings transitions. That's why `replace` doesn't work.